# How to manage this dictionary in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
dict = {(0,1):"SomeText",(0,2):"SomeText",(2,1):"SomeText"}
```

I stored a 10x10 table in `dict` in above format, which I need to display in Table format in Django HTML template.

Comment: Where does `dict` come from? Why isn't it a 2d array?

Comment: It might be better to convert this ridiculous data structure to something better suited for this task in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can splice this into an 10x10 table in a oneliner. In case your dict is called "mydict" (avoid the name dict for a variable) this would mean you hand over the following list to the template renderer:

```
[[mydict[(i,j)] for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

If not all elements are present you can introduce an if statement in this one line.

.